# caching controllers names for routes

Tags: php, slim

so in my application I have plenty of controllers with each has it own slug public property. I instantiate these controllers, get their slugs and bind them to my Router.

```
<?php
  $controllers = goThroughControllerFolder($folder); // and get files
  foreach($controllers as $controller) {
    $slug = (new $controller)->slug;
    $application->get($slug, function() { //some random callback });
  }
```

for each controller I've to create a new instance on every run and get the slug, and bind to the Router which isn't very performance oriented. How would I go about creating something on the first run to make these route assignments even more faster on subsequent runs.

what I've tried,
I have created `routes.php` which simply returns an array. I would append to it `controller_name` and `slug` or other data and access it later on.

I've measured the performance with around 8-10 controller files with `microtime()` -- with and without routes.php -- but it's almost the same.

I know there are php based platforms that do these sort of things. the question, how?

Note: I respect the community. so if you find this question not attractive enough. lemme know in the comments and I'll drop it right away.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: well I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear enough. what I wanna know is that the approach that I'm using to init my routes (the slim thing) by looping through each controller file rather than specifying the routes individually --- is it performance wise right?? mainly because, on every run, I'm creating a new instance of every controller, getting their slug, and then binding it to get (route).

Comment: Manually add routes or adding it in loops will not make big difference in term of performance, But to me, it does not make it any clearer nor add any benefits.

Comment: I think you have the answer, just did not implement it. The piece of code you posted successfully extracts slugs for controllers. You can use this same code to generate a static routes definition file and include it in your app. Every time you add a new controller to your application (which does not happen frequently) you can re-generate the routes file, and you'll need this only once after you add new controller. But to be honest, if you have so many controllers that you ran into some problem like this, then probably something is wrong with your design.